# How to force functions in an object to be evaluated each time the object is referenced?

Tags: javascript, object

If I create an object, such as:

```
var obj = {
   val1: 1,
   val2: Math.random()
   };
```

When the object is instantiated, Math.random() is immediately evaluated and the result assigned to obj.val2.

Every future reference to obj.val2 will return this initial random number.

Is there a way to force this function to be re-evaluated each time the object is referenced?  So every reference to obj.val2 will re-run Math.random(), yielding a newly generated random number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), this way every time you access the property you can run a function that returns a new value each time.

```js
var obj = {
   val1: 1,
   get val2() {
      return Math.random();
   }
};
   
console.log(obj.val2)
console.log(obj.val2)
```

Comment: A `get` function in a literal is definitely the right tool for this simple case. I might also point out [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more complex cases.

Comment: I wish `var obj = {
       val1: 1,
       get val2: Math.random
    };` was valid syntactic sugar.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!